# URL rewrite on core PHP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL from

```
example.com/file.php?id=yes
```

To

```
example.com/file.php/yes
```

Website is on core PHP

I have tried the below code in `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html /abc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What could `^([0-9]+).html` possibly match here, in your opinion?

Comment: Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1427878

Comment: Why do you want to "_rewrite_" the URL from `/file.php?id=yes` to `/file.php/yes`? Is this for "cosmetic" reasons or is there some underlying technical issue you are trying to resolve? (Because, on the face of it, this doesn't really make sense in practical terms.)

Comment: Actually i want to do it due to cosmetic reason and also make this SEO friendly

Comment: I need urgent help in this, So let me know if you can do

Comment: So, the existing URL structure is `/file.php?id=yes` and you want to change it to `/file.php/yes`? Or is this a new site and you want to implement a URL structure like `/file.php/yes` from the start?

Comment: @MrWhite I want to apply first scenerio

Comment: _“I need urgent help in this”_ - we don’t do “urgent” here, please go and read the link I posted above. If you _need_ an urgent solution, then feel free to go and pay someone somewhere to implement it for you. Otherwise, _participate_ in the development of the solution at least. I asked you a specific question, so please try and respond to that first of all.

Comment: Have you already changed the URL in your application to the new form, ie. `/file.php/yes`?

Comment: @MrWhite, Yes, I have, Now I just want to redirect example.com/file.php?id=yes
 to example.com/file.php/yes

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file.php/(.*)$ file.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I have, Now I just want to redirect `example.com/file.php?id=yes` to `example.com/file.php/yes`

In order to preserve SEO, having changed the URL structure you could implement an external redirect like this, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /$0/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the complete match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `file.php`). And the `%1` backreference (note the `%`) contains the value of the `id` URL parameter from the preceding *CondPattern*.

The `QSD` flag is necessary to *discard* the original query string from the redirected request.

Note you should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect in order to avoid potential caching issues.

*Aside:*

> Actually i want to do it due to cosmetic reason and also make this SEO friendly

Although, there's not really any difference SEO-wise between these two URLs. In fact, simply *changing* the URL structure you could have a short term negative effect on SEO.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html /abc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This appears to do the opposite and something quite different from your intended action...

It would *internally rewrite* (not "redirect") a URL of the form `/0123456789.html?foo=1` to `/abc.php?id=0123456789&foo=1`

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite the URL from example.com/file.php?id=yes to example.com/file.php/yes using .htaccess, you can modify your RewriteRule as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^file.php$ /file.php/%1? [R=301,L]
```

This code first checks if the query string matches the pattern id=something, where "something" can be any value. If it does, it then performs a 301 redirect (permanent redirect) to the desired URL format by capturing the value of "something" (the (.+) part in the RewriteCond pattern) and appending it to the new URL as a path segment using %1. The ? at the end of the RewriteRule removes the query string from the redirected URL.

Make sure to replace file.php with your actual PHP file name, and adjust the paths accordingly if your website is located in a subdirectory.

Please note that this code will issue a permanent redirect (HTTP 301), so make sure to test it thoroughly, and once you are sure it's working correctly, you can change [R=301,L] to [L] to make it an internal rewrite without the redirect, if desired.